# SVD decomposition to UV decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Let's say I have an SVD decomposition of a matrix $M$ of size $m\times n$: $M = A\sum B$ where $A:m\times m, \sum:m\times n, B: n\times n$. I want to convert it to $M = UV$ where $U:m\times d$, $V: d\times n$. What are the algorithms to do so ? Are there any parallel ones ?

I have one idea is that first, UV decompose the diagonal matrix $\sum$ into two matrices $\sum = L\times L'$ where $L:m\times d, L'=d\times n$. Then, $U = AL$ and $V=L'B$. But this requires UV decomposition of a diagonal matrix.

**Edit**

d is a predefined constant and $d < min(m,n)$.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did $d$ come from? FWIW: do you already know about "thin SVD"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cholesky Factorization instead, if you don't want to use $UV$ decomposition. But seems you still need to know more about the SVD itself. I think this may help: http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/svd.pdf

Comment: And if the matrix is ill-conditioned (which might be exactly the reason why one might bother with SVD)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's good to check the conditioning first. Here is an easy way to check ill-conditioning:
Check the condition number of your matrix using $cond(A)=||A||||A^{-1}||$. When this number is very large then your matrix is ill-conditioned and you can use any norm for that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a full-rank factorization?

$$
  \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}\,\mathbf{C}
$$
with 
$$
 \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}, \quad 
 \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times \rho}, \quad 
 \mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{C}^{\rho\times n}.
$$
To compute this factorization compute the row reduction 
$$
 \mathbf{A} \mapsto \mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{A}}.
$$
The recipe uses the $\rho$ basic columns of $\mathbf{A}$ for the columns of $\mathbf{B}$,
$$
 \mathbf{B} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
  \mathbf{A}_{*,1} & \mathbf{A}_{*,2} & \dots & \mathbf{A}_{*,\rho}
\end{array} \right]
$$
and use the row vectors of the reduced matrix $\mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{A}}$ for the row vectors of $\mathbf{C}$,
$$
\mathbf{C} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 
  {\mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{A}}}_{1,*} \\\hline
  {\mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{A}}}_{2,*} \\\hline
    \vdots \\\hline
  {\mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{A}}}_{\rho,*}
\end{array} \right].
$$

**Example**

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} &\mapsto \mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{A}} \\
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{2} & 2 & 3 \\
 \color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{4} & 1 & 3 \\
 \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{6} & 1 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
&\mapsto 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{2} & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} \\
 \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{1} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}\, \mathbf{C} &= \mathbf{A} \\
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{2} \\
 \color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{1} \\
 \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{2} & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} \\
 \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right] 
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
 3 & 6 & 1 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
$$